# VB.Net Noob: How do I use a window like a function - pass in parameters, use the window, then get data out when it closes?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class, function

I've got a pretty simple problem, I think. I'm using WPF in Visual Basic 2010 (Express, but I don't think that alters my question.)

I am creating a window that is a generic keypad for editing numerical values on a touchscreen. I would like to press an 'edit' button to create a copy of the keypad window/bring up a reusable version of the same window (I don't care), but pass in parameters: the old value I'm manipulating, and a title to be displayed above the number pad.

I would like the user to be able to type in the new value, then press the 'done' key to submit this value and have it sent back to the main application window into my custom control that contains a text box.

(I have the number pad's layout sorted out already; I'm already using a variation on it to set a global password 'access level'. It's getting the information in and out that has me scratching my head.)

If I were calling a function, it would be this simple:

```
textBoxValue = changeMyValue("window title", oldTextBoxValue)
```

But when it becomes a window class, I get a bit confused.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried adding the parameters you want to pass to the constructor for the keypad window and just passing the values you need in there? there are also more elegant ways to go about this is you are using MVVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a method which creates a window, gets the value and passes it back. e.g.

```
public int ChangeMyValue(string title, string oldvalue)
{
    var window = new KeyPadWindow(title, oldvalue);
    window.ShowDialog();
    return window.Value;
}
```

Assumes that you need an `int` and that the dialog does some conversion and exposes the value in a property called `Value`.

Comment: OK, I guess it's fairly obvious when I remember the window is a class (duh) and just manipulate the data as if it were any other random class I had created. I'm assuming an appropriate location for this ChangeMyValue subroutine would be inside the MyCustomControl class, since many instances of this custom control are going to be creating instances of the keypad and acting on their output?

Comment: Methods should be where they are needed, so sure, why not.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it doing exactly what I wanted... and it doesn't feel like a hack. Straightforward concept, I know, but woohoo! I'll take whatever victories I can get.